# using enum elements properly

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

Assuming I have these files, like this:

A.h

```
namespace cool
{
  class A
  {
    public:
      enum Status {OK, NotOK, NotOK2};
   };
}
```

B.h

```
#include "A.h"
namespace cool
{
  class B
  {
    public:
      A::Status doSth(int param1);
  };
}
```

B.cpp

```
using cool::A;
using cool::B;

A::Status B::doSth(int param1)
{
  return A::Status::OK;
}
```

So my problem is that I don't want to write `A::Status::OK`, whenever I want to return a Status type. Is there a way to just return `OK`? Or `Status::OK`, so that I can at least save some time not writing the class name every time.

I have obviously tried so far adding `using cool::A::Status;`, `using A::Status;` and `using cool::A::Status::OK;`. But then I get the compile error:

> 'cool::A' is not a namespace or unscoped enum

Any ideas on how to just needing to return OK?

Comment: *"I don't want to write `A::Status::OK`"* Good news - you don't have to, as it won't compile anyway. The correct syntax is `return A::OK;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ah nice ty that already helped out a lot, is there also a way to just return OK?

Comment: Define the enum at namespace scope, outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:
You already can remove `Status::`

```
return A::/*Status::*/OK;
```

Solution 2: 
You can move `enum Status {OK, NAK, MAK};` outside of class A

Solution 3: make a `#define` called `OK`

```
#define OK A::Status::OK
```